# How could I solve " you can't chang 'dbo.tb_dept_change' , because it is a Incompatible object types"?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have two tables, they are dbo.tb_dept_change and dbo.tb_employee. I need to alter the trigger, but it notices 消息 2010，级别 16，状态 1，过程 tb_dept_change，第 21 行无法对 'dbo.tb_dept_change' 进行更改，因为它是不兼容的对象类型.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tb_dept_change] ON  [dbo].[tb_employee]

FOR UPDATE

AS

if ( COLUMNS_UPDATED() &7) >0

    BEGIN

    if ((select employee_dept from Deleted ) <> (select employee_dept from Inserted))

begin

    insert into tb_dept_change

    (ch_date)

    values(getdate())

    update tb_dept_change set ch_source =Deleted.employee_dept, ch_duty_source = Deleted.employee_duty from Deleted

    update tb_dept_change set ch_destination = Inserted.employee_dept, ch_duty_Destination = Inserted.employee_duty from Inserted

    update tb_dept_change set ch_employee = Deleted.employee_id from Deleted
```

Comment: looks like `tb_dept_change` is a table. Why is your trigger also named `tb_dept_change` ? see `ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tb_dept_change] ON [dbo].[tb_employee]`

Comment: Also your trigger query is not correct. Every time the trigger is fired, it changes all values of column `ch_source`, `ch_destination` & `ch_employee` for all rows

Comment: I see, I try use "create TRIGGER [deptchange] ON  [dbo].[tb_employee]" it is okay. And then I change it to "ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deptchange] ON  [dbo].[tb_employee]".

Comment: Finally, it is okay to run. Thank you for your help.